# Why can't typescript infer these correlated types?

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-inference

Having the following code:

```
const foo = (flag: boolean) => {
  if (flag) {
    return {
       success: true,
       data: {
         name: "John",
         age: 40
       }
    }
  }

  return {
    success: false,
    data: null
  }
}    

const result = foo(true);

if (result.success) {
   console.log(result.data.name); // TS error: 'result.data' is possibly 'null'
}
```

Why can't typescript infer that `data` always exists if `flag` is set to `true`?

I know I can fix this by defining a return type for the function, but it'd be good if TS automatically infers it.

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but I suspect it's because the static analysis of the function produces one overall return type. It's not trying to follow what happens when the constant `true` is passed to the function.

Comment: try returning `as const`

Comment: So what *does* TypeScript infer as the type of  `result`?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `as const` or create a discriminated union around your `success` property.

Using `as const`:

```
const foo = (flag: boolean) => {
  if (flag) {
    return {
       success: true,
       data: {
         name: "John",
         age: 40
       }
    } as const; // here
  }

  return {
    success: false,
    data: null
  } as const; // here
}    

const result = foo(true);

if (result.success) {
   console.log(result.data.name);
}
```

Using a union:

```
type Successful = {
   success: true;
   data: { name: string, age: number }
}

type Failed {
   success: false;
   data: null;
}

type Result = Successful | Failed;

function foo(flag: boolean): Result {
  if (flag) {
    return {
       success: true,
       data: {
         name: "John",
         age: 40
       }
    };
  }

  return {
    success: false,
    data: null
  };
}    

const result = foo(true);

if (result.success) {
   console.log(result.data.name);
}
```

Why this happens is that just assigning `true` or `false`, TypeScript infers that property to a `boolean` so the `data: null` case, it can't prove that `{ success: true, data: null }` won't happen. There's also no type information that `flag` has to relate to the return type. That is where generics help.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code fix:

```
interface ReturnSuccess {
  success: true
  data: { name: string; age: number }
}
interface ReturnFailure {
  success: false
  data: null
}
const foo = <Flag extends boolean, Return extends Flag extends true ? ReturnSuccess : ReturnFailure>(flag: Flag): Return {
  if (flag) {
    return {
       success: true,
       data: {
         name: "John",
         age: 40
       }
    } as Return 
  }

  return {
    success: false,
    data: null
  } as Return 
}
```

Comment: avoid the `as` in the return.

Comment: I think OP is more concerned why `if (result.success) {` does not discriminate the union, not why they can't access `foo(true).data.name` directly.